# using protractor mouseMove to click on a drop-down

Tags: protractor

I am using the following to get protractor to click on a drop-down menu.

```
 ptor.actions().mouseMove(
        ptor.findElement(protractor.By.xpath("//a[@tooltip='Portfolios']"))
      ).click();
```

However this does nothing which is to say that the drop-down does not get clicked and no errors are displayed.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of those who landed on this page. The solution is to use .perform at the end.

here is the working version

```
ptor.actions().mouseMove(
        ptor.findElement(protractor.By.xpath("//a[@tooltip='Portfolios']"))
      ).click().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't have to use actions, with actions you can not select option that is not currently visible in the screen.
use this:

```
element(by.xpath("//a[@tooltip='Portfolios']")).click();
```

Comment: this option didn't work for me and it could be because my list is generated using ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should only use perform, like:

```
 ptor.actions().mouseMove(
        ptor.findElement(protractor.By.xpath("//a[@tooltip='Portfolios']"))
      ).perform();
```